# How do I fix 'brew install pkg-config'?

Tags: homebrew, pkg-config

```
Warning: Could not link pkg-config. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link pkg-config`‏‏‏‏‏‏
```

Answer (score 24):

1. brew reinstall pkg-config
2. rm -R offending-directory
3. repeat step 1

Comment: is there a similar solution to this but for ubuntu?

Comment: third step is useless or should be `brew unlink pkg-config && brew link pkg-config`

Comment: You can merge the first three steps with `brew reinstall pkg-config`.

Answer (score 9):

As Michael Pigg said above, in my case it was the folder permission issue.
I had to do the following:

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/share/man/man1
brew link pkg-config
```

And after I'm done:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/share/man/man1
```

to restore the original permissions.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a permissions issue on /usr/local/share. You need to have write permission in that directory for the link to complete. However, zsh will complain about the directory being insecure if you set the write permission. I gave the write permission to allow pkg-config to install and then removed it so that zsh would be happy.

Answer (score 1):

1. reinstall command line tools: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action
2. brew link --overwrite --dry-run pkg-config

Comment: `--dry-run` will prevent the linkage