# Unable to run zmq for golang on a mac os X, unknown issue

Tags: go, zeromq

I was trying to use [gozmq](https://github.com/alecthomas/gozmq) for my go project with ZMQ however, I was having some problems and wasn't really sure what the problem was.

When I run my application with zmq as in:

```
$ go run main.go
```

I get back:

```
# pkg-config --cflags libzmq libzmq libzmq libzmq 
exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I don't actually know what it means or why it comes up. However, I guessed that I didn't install zmq or it cannot find it or something...so I brew installed it with

```
brew install zmq
```

But I get:

```
Warning: zeromq-4.0.4 already installed
```

So I know that I already installed it. Even though its installed it doesn't work, weird?

The instruction at [gozmq](https://github.com/alecthomas/gozmq) do say to run for 4.x install with:

```
go get -tags zmq_4_x github.com/alecthomas/gozmq
```

I literally ran:

go get -tags zmq_4_x github.com/alecthomas/gozmq

and

go get -tags zmq_4_0 github.com/alecthomas/gozmq

and

go get -tags zmq_4_0_4 github.com/alecthomas/gozmq

I thought the last one would work since it matches the version I had but non of the above worked.

In fact they all just returned the familiar error:

```
# pkg-config --cflags libzmq libzmq libzmq libzmq
exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in $PATH
```

As a last resource I tried to go to (the official site) at:

http://zeromq.org/docs:source-git

to install it but the instruction they have for MAC OS X and Unix-like systems does not work for my computer. Does anyone know whats going on? What else should I try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix 'brew install pkg-config'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483059/how-do-i-fix-brew-install-pkg-config)

Comment: that is very similar. Wonder why it didn't come up when I searched, thanks for the link I will take a look at it for sure

Comment: I googled for **brew pkg-config**, SO's search is usually useless 99% of the time.

Comment: @Pinocchio: It's complaining that it can't find `pkg-config` in your `$PATH`. Have you installed `pkg-config`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem for pkg-config was easy to solve. I just brew installed it as the duplicate suggested.

However,if you look a little closer, I had 4.0.4. Which seems to be a version of zmq that is not properly supported by gozmq (or it doesn't work because it has errors thrown by the compiler).

I had to then go and brew install zmq but version 3.2.4 and then install the gozmq version for that zmq version.

To do that read [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) that shows you how to install a specific version of anything in brew.