# brew doctor Error: "No available formula with the name "pkg-config" "

Tags: homebrew

I just installed Homebrew on Windows using the Linux Bash Shell but I have this error when I run `brew doctor`  :

> Error: No available formula with the name "pkg-config"

what can i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix 'brew install pkg-config'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483059/how-do-i-fix-brew-install-pkg-config)

Answer (score 1):

First, update Homebrew so it is pulling from the right resources: `brew update`
Run `brew doctor` again.

If the same error occurs, try doing a `brew search pkg-config` and see which results come up. I've had cases where the path to the package was different than usual. Pick one of the search results, and then do a `brew install` with the package path from the search results: `brew install /homebrew/searchresultpath/pkg-config`

Hopefully the correct path for the extension will solve your problem.